# Execute User Script without tampermonkey or another

Tags: javascript, userscripts, chromium-embedded

I want execute this user script without tampermonkey or another.
already that i use Chromium Embedded Framework and i can't use a tampermonkey for this.

window.stop(),document.documentElement.innerHTML=null,GM_xmlhttpRequest({method:"GET",url:"http://extension.agarplus.io",onload:function(e){document.open(),document.write(e.responseText),document.close()}});

so I need to run this code how that you run a common javascript

Answer (score 1):

May be this will help you:

> The simplest way to execute JS from a client application is using the
>   CefFrame::ExecuteJavaScript() function

https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/JavaScriptIntegration

Comment: I don't have idea how execute it in c#
normally i use Browser.ExecuteScriptAsync();

Like this:

string script = "javascript code here";
Browser.ExecuteScriptAsync(script);